# document.add resize the document using iText

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfptable

When I try to read an HTML file (using HTMLWorker.parseToList) and create a PDF document using document.add(element) the resulting page is getting resized. The initially set page size is getting overridden, it appears the page is resizing itself to fit the incoming component. I am wondering is there any way we can control this? I noticed that there is no scaletofit avaialable for PdfPTable. How do you resize a PdfPTable?

Comment: I am seeing the output as 8.26 X 11.69 vs 8.5 X 11 in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have to withdraw this question as I am seeing the library working correct nof. I was confused on A4 vs Letter size. "A4 and US letter size are very similar in size and can be used in the same way. A4 size is thinner and longer than US letter size US letter size is wider and shorter than A4 size"